# vcpkg to install wxWidgts but getting include errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, wxwidgets, vcpkg

As the title says I used vcpkg to install wxWidgets. I then ran ./vcpkg integrate install and it says applied user wide integration. The wxWidgets doc says I should be able to use the wxWidget headers now in my project, but VSC is still giving me this error:

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
// error = #include errors detected. Please update your includePath.
```

I checked my includePath for visual studio code and there are two paths

```
"${workspaceFolder}/**",
"${vcpkgRoot}/x64-osx/include"
```

Any ideas?

Ive tried adding these paths

```
/Users/ryne/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_x64-osx/include/wx-3.1 

/Users/ryne/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include
```

but didn't work

Comment: I think you are using the wrong the include folder. For me on windows its `X:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include` and not in the packages folder.

Comment: If you had not had integration active before installing wx did you restart VSC after doing the integration? (I don't know that this would make a difference but would certainly try it).

Comment: Just restarted VSC and still getting error and edited the path i added that leads up to wx/wxprec.h

Comment: aw okay I'll try /Users/ryne/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include

Comment: I was reading through some microsoft forum's and it seems like visual studio code is not supported for vcpkg?

Comment: Does `/Users/ryne/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include` contain a `wx` folder?

Comment: Yup and that contains the header files im including

Comment: @Ryne Are you using CMake? Try adding this and see if this works for you? Find the `.vscode` folder, create `settings.json` and add this `"cmake.configureSettings": {    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE":[vcpkg root]scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" }` 
If not, you might need to do something [like this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4002)

Comment: @Ryne Any progress here?  I'm stuck in the same place. Note: I do know that `${vcpkgRoot}` = `/Users/ryne/vcpkg/installed` .  That location holds the .h files which helps my intellisense, but no where are the object files linked; hence a compile fail. I'm curious if you got this to work.  Possible to share all of your .vscode files? thx.

Comment: Sorry I made no progress on this, but I didn't try the cmake solution proposed by @segmentation_fault . I should get back to it soon ill keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

Go to your vcpkg folder and type `vcpkg integrate install`, it will automatically add path and links to your visual studio whenever you install any packages.

**NOTE:** You should run command with administration privellage